# Authorization in GraphQL servers

Tags: authorization, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

How to handle Authorization in GraphQL servers?

Shall I pass the JWT token in the Authentication header of every requests and check for the authorized user after `resolve()` and check for the role of user on every `query` and `mutation`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Introduction

First of all, a common approach for *authentication* as you state is using a signed JWT that contains the id of the user making the request.

Now let's have a look at the different *parameters* we can use when considering the *authorization* of a given request.

- **who is making the request?**

  determined by the user id mentioned above. More information about the requester like associated user roles can be looked up in the database. This means that we need to maintain a `User` table if we are using SQL for example, and add new users to this table on registration.
- **which operation should be executed?**

  users might be granted read-only access. Certain mutations or queries are only allowed for certain users.
- **which fields are included in the query/mutation response?**

  some fields should be only accessed by certain users.

## Permissions

With this information in mind, we can come up with different permission systems. Most commonly, in such a system, no operation is allowed by default. When a request comes in, the parameters mentioned above can be matched with the existing permissions and if a matching permission is found, the request is granted.

### Role-based permissions

In certain applications, a role-based approach works great. 
For example, for a simpler version of Stack Overflow, we could have the roles `EVERYONE`, `AUTHENTICATED` and `MODERATOR`. A sensible permission rule could be this:

- `EVERYONE` can read questions/answers

  - **requester**: doesn't matter (everyone)
  - **operations**: `allQuestions`, `allAnswers` queries
  - **fields**: `text`

Other rules (leaving parameters out):
* `AUTHENTICATED` users can create new questions/answers
* `MODERATOR` users can create new questions/answers
* `MODERATOR` users can delete questions/answers.

Now for example, if a non-authenticated requests comes in that asks for the `allQuestions` query, that's fine as we find a permission that allows it (the first).

If on the other hand an authenticated requests comes in for a user that doesn't have the `MODERATOR` role and includes the `deleteQuestion` mutation, there is no permission to be found for these parameters. So the request is rejected.

### Graph permissions

While role-based permissions represent a solid permission system already, they are not suited at all if we want to make granting permission dependant on things like the relation between the requester and the requested node. In our example, it would be quite the work to add the simple rule that any user is allowed to delete their own questions/answers.

At [Graphcool](http://graph.cool), we have come up with a powerful yet rather simple approach that we call **graph permissions** to tackle this issue. Let's make the following additional **parameters** available when checking permissions:

- **which node is about to be accessed or modified?**

  determined by a node id

Then we can express permissions using a GraphQL query against a special **permission schema** to grant or reject permissions on a node level. Access to a given node is only given, if the permission query contains at least one leaf-node that is not `null`.

In our case, we could specify this permission query:

```
query {
  allAnswers(filter:{
      authorId: $userId,
      id: $nodeId
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

For a given node and user specified by GraphQL variables `$userId` and `$nodeId`, we use a query argument `filter` to either return an empty list if the node wasn't created by the current user, or something non-null otherwise.