# How do I return the id property of the user object in Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, auth0, apollo, graphcool

When I place the below in a React component that queries the user model I am able to get the entire user object as queried by graphQL including the id property:

```
console.log(this.props.data.user)
```

But when I try to access the id property from code:

```
console.log(this.props.data.user) // undefined 
console.log(this.props.data.user.id)
 // error cannot get property of undefined
```

My first guess is that this is a security feature; I am using Auth0 and Graphcool.

But I may just be going about this in a backwards way. If so, any help on accessing the user id in the correct manner would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the [FAQ article on the logged in user](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphcool-session-user-goij0cooqu).

## Obtaining a Signed JWT with Auth0

The `user` query returns the currently authenticated user. So first we have to think about how the authenticated user is determined.

The current state-of-the-art is [using verified JWT](https://auth0.com/blog/building-an-instagram-clone-with-graphql-and-auth0/) and passing them as the `Authorization` header.

After entering valid credentials in Auth0 Lock, it returns a JWT that is signed with your secret Auth0 key. This signed JWT is sent to the GraphQL server where we'll use your Auth0 key to verify it and if it belongs to a valid user, the request is authenticated.

## Setting the `Authorization` Header with Apollo Client

So I suspect that you're simply not passing a valid `Authorization` header. With Apollo, you can use this to ensure passing the token if it is present. Note that we'll use local storage for storing the token from Auth0 Lock:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({ uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/__PROJECT_ID__' })

// use the auth0IdToken in localStorage for authorized requests
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware (req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {}
    }

    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth0IdToken')) {
      req.options.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('auth0IdToken')}`
    }
    next()
  },
}])

const client = new ApolloClient({ networkInterface })
```

Check [this Auth0 example code](https://github.com/graphcool-examples/react-apollo-auth0-example) or [the live demo](http://apollo-auth0.netlify.com) to see how it works.

You might also be interested in [this answer on authorization (permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206123/authorization-in-graphql-servers/41213017#41213017).

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually using the github project you have suggested. It is working with authentication, queries, mutations, the whole works.

Comment: Can you please add more context around your code? Maybe you're accessing `data` before `data.loading`.

Comment: Before `data.loading` is false, that is.

Comment: Thanks both..That was the issue.